# Gitlab-runner shell executor suddenly error on ssl

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Yesterday my shell executor worked fine with default test yml:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script: echo "Running tests"

build:
  stage: build
  script: echo "Building the app"

deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy to staging server"
    - export
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  only:
  - master
```

But now i get the follow error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.3.0 (5cf5e19a)
  on gitlab01ShellSQLRunner (9ec36953)
Using Shell executor...
Running on debian...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/9ec36953/0/dev/SQL'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@10.45.18.14/dev/SQL.git/': SSL: certificate subject name (Gitlab01) does not match target host name '10.45.18.14'
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

This is I fail to understand because of three things:
1. The runners url is https://gitlab01 (why does it use ip suddenly?)
2. The ip matches the url https://gitlab01.YXNET.local ~ aliased https://gitlab01
3. It worked yesterday:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.3.0 (5cf5e19a)
  on gitlabShellRunner (d36a5267)
Using Shell executor...
Running on debian...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 6e9a125 added CI/CD file
From https://gitlab01/dev/SQL
   6e9a125..84de9fd  master     -> origin/master
Checking out 84de9fd7 as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
$ echo "Running tests"
Running tests
Job succeeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened in this case, was that I'd restarted the debian machine, which had reset the hostname... So no hostname makes gitlab use the IP per default...

Checking the ip, for SSL certificates makes it not find it...

Wonder why it keeps losing my hostname everytime I reboot the linux machine, but that's how it is...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error with the connection on the gitlab runner... 
therefore i added into  `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
       GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "true"
```

and gitlab runner was able to connect and cloning the repo.

Comment: Generally it would be better to FIX security that just to disable it.